# format a json of a class in spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am new with spring and I want the json response of my class

`public class Mapping { public String name; public Object value; }`

be changed from

`{"name" : 'value of field name', "value": 'value of field value'}`
to

`{'value of field name' : 'value of field value'}`

I tried `@JsonValue` and `@JsonKey` but they didn`t work. how can I do this.

edit:
I want to set the value of key dynamically and based on value of the field `name`.

edit_P2:
this class, is a model for a single field in json, means an object of it must hold one key and value of my json, like a map, it has key and values, and what i want is to store key in field 'name' and the value in outher field, so when i return this object, it returns the string in field 'name' as key and the other one as value, lets assume name="the key" and value="the value", i want it to be return as "the key":"the value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited in reaction to your comment:
Have your class changed from

```
public class Mapping { 
   public String name; 
   public Object value; 
}
```

to simply this:

```
public class Mapping { 
   public String name; 
}
```

and in your code to this:

```
Mapping myMapping = new Mapping();
myMapping.name = "myValue";
```

This will be parsed to JSON: `{"name":"myValue"}`

**Additional edit**
OK, I think I understood what you want and I think it might be impossible in a single json serialization. Your options would be to create a custom serializer See this article: [Jackson – Custom Serializer](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization). Or (in my opinion simpler way) add a method to your class `toMap()` that will produce your desired map and than convert that map to Json. That will give you desired Json. BTW for simple Json serializer/deserializer that is a wrapper over Json-Jackson library look here: [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The library could be found as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc).

**Original answer**:

You need to use annotation `@JsonProperty` and its attribute "name". Here is a good article about it: [Jackson – Change Name of Field](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-name-of-property)

Comment: with all respect, it is not what i want, i want the key to be dynamic and get its value from field name

Comment: Thanks for yor edit
But let me do a demonstration of what i want
Well, this class, is a model for a single field of my json, means an object of it must hold one key and value of my json, like a map, it has key and values, and what i want is to store key in field 'name' and the value in outher field, so when i return this object, it returns the string in field 'name' as key and the other one as value, lets assume name="the key" and value="the value", i want it to be return as "the key":"the value".

Comment: See my reply in additional edit in the answer

Comment: Thanks for your response and updates and consistency ofcourse, it is know understandable to me, i appreciate that